# Accidentally installed Apache Tomcat on live server, how to undo?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, apt-get

I installed Tomcat on the live server by accident using apt-get and broke it. Is there a easy way to undo the installation and go back to the way it was before? I have a virtual image from awhile ago but am wondering if there is a way to just undo it?

EDIT: The server was just running apache without tomcat before.

Comment: So there was already a Tomcat installed? Do you know where, perhaps `/usr/local/` or in someone's homedir? You could `dpkg --remove` the newly installed tomcat, but you'd have to be sure that the old tomcat isn't installed in the same location and was overwritten, otherwise the original installation will be removed..

Comment: there was not Tomcat before. it was just on regular apache and now it's messed up.

Comment: Ok, then just `dpkg --remove` or `dpkg --purge` the tomcat package. It probably modified your apache config by enabling `mod_jk`; uninstalling it would undo the configuration change.

Comment: Thanks I ran `sudo apt-get remove tomcat7` I guess that is the same as dpkg. Everything went back to working.

Comment: Yes, it's the same - Debian guy here, sorry, I assumed it was the same :-) Good that it's working again!